# How to avoid backslash escape when writing regular expression in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, regex

For regular expression \w+\d, in many script language such as perl/python it can be written literally. But in C/C++, I must write it as:

```
const char *re_str = "\\w+\\d";
```

which is ugly to eye.

Is there any method to avoid it? MACRO are also acceptable.

Comment: That is the language syntax for char array literals.  The alternative is probably even worse:  `'\', 'w', '+', '\', 'd', '\0'`

Comment: @Amardeep: Does `'\'` even work? wouldn't that \ be misinterpreted as `\'`?

Comment: @sbi: You are quite correct. The escaping isn't limited just to double quote literals but affects character literals as well.  I should have known since I put the \0 in there for a terminator.  :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I reading [C: A reference manual] Chapter 3: Prepressors. An idea emerges:

```
 #define STR(a) #a
 #define R(var, re)  static char var##_[] = STR(re);\
 const char * var = ( var##_[ sizeof(var##_) - 2] = '\0',  (var##_ + 1) );

 R(re, "\w\d");
 printf("Hello, world[%s]\n",  re);
```

It's portable in both C and C++, only uses standard preprocessing features. The trick is to use macro to expand \ inside liternal string and then remove the leading and tailing double quote strings.

Now I think it's the best way until C++0x really introduce the new literal string syntax R"...". And for C I think it'll be the best way for a long time.

The side effect is that we cannot defined such a variable in the global scope in C. Because there's a statement to remove the tailing double-quote character. In C++ it's OK.

Comment: This is the True Solution. Backwards and Forwards compatible.

Comment: Does this macro have any drawbacks? Is it unsave to use it?

Comment: The only potential drawback I can see is that the pattern expression created this way is modifiable.

Answer (score 10):

Just as an FYI, the next C++ standard (C++ 0x) will have something called [raw string literals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#New_string_literals) which should let you do something like:

```
const char *re_str = R"(\w+\d)";
```

However until then I think you're stuck with the pain of doubling up your backslashes if you want the regex to be a literal in the source file.

Comment: Great! Thank you, This is the dream feature for me about C++. But unfortunately It's not usable at present and for C it's even worse.

Comment: I check it with vc2010, does not support yet: error C3861: 'R': identifier not found

Answer (score 2):

You can put your regexp in a file and read the file if you have a lot or need to modify them often. That's the only way I see to avoid backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is only one kind of string literals in C++, and it's the kind that treats escaped characters.