# Regular Expression Library for C++03

Tags: c++, regex, c++03

I have a string of this format that I need to verify:

> H12345-001

Here the first character should be an alphabetical character followed by 5 digits, then a dash (`-`), then two zeroes and finally a digit.

I am not sure if regex is right choice or can do it in a naive way of comparing each character. If regex is right way to go can someone point out to an example tutorials to use it. I am using C++03 (i.e. no C++11).

Comment: There's [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html). Or [Poco's Regex](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.RegularExpression.html). But this is so simple I wouldn't bring in a whole new library just for this (if you're already using a library that provides regex, sure, use it). Otherwise, I'd just verify this with a custom function.

Comment: We are not using Boost in our proj. Thats why I have to decide if I have to bring in boost to validate our string or can just check char by character. Just wanna seek expert advise if I'm thinking right

Comment: "C++ 3.0"? Do you mean Borland Turbo C++ 3.0? If so, that's positively antique.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your string can include a lowercase letter, the regex is `[a-zA-z]\d\d\d\d\d-00\d` (just remove the `a-z` if you don't want lowercase letters).

Simple custom validator if bringing in a regex library isn't worth it ([demo](http://ideone.com/6ux9d1)):

```
bool isValid(const std::string& str)
{
    return
        (str.size() == 10) &&
        (('a' <= str[0] && str[0] <= 'z') ||
        ('A' <= str[0] && str[0] <= 'Z')) &&
        ('0' <= str[1] && str[1] <= '9') &&
        ('0' <= str[2] && str[2] <= '9') &&
        ('0' <= str[3] && str[3] <= '9') &&
        ('0' <= str[4] && str[4] <= '9') &&
        ('0' <= str[5] && str[5] <= '9') &&
        (str[6] == '-' && str[7] == '0' && str[8] == '0') &&
        ('0' <= str[9] && str[9] <= '9');
}
```

Comment: I think there are `isalpha()` and `isdigit()` functions for such purpose

Comment: Yup. They're provided under `<cctype>` or `<locale>` for the locale aware versions.

Comment: @Slava: Yes, but those rely on the current locale. I haven't given enough thought to locales in this answer to suggest those two functions, so I've ignored them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) for this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

boost::regex your_regex("[A-Z]\\d{5}-00\\d");
boost::smatch match;

int main() {
    std::string input = "H12345-001";
    std::string output;
    if(boost::regex_match(input, match, your_regex)) {
        output = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(match);
        std::cout << output << std::endl;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

This is an example for matching a single occurrence, you will need to adjust it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Any regex library will do. There's pcre for POISX systems, for example, where you just `#include <regex.h>` and call the `regcomp` family of functions ( [man 3 regcomp](http://man.cx/regcomp(3)) for more info). Nothing in those should require C++11.

Frankly, if you're going with regexes, which for this problem doesn't seem to be worth it, the one difficult issue will be to have the regex pattern proper in the C++ code, because of having to escape all the backslashes and stuff. You might want to try [this awesome solution here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3985120/399580) to work with the regexes in C++<11 without much problem.

Otherwise, go with Cornstalk's answer.

Answer (score -1):

This regex is pretty bad but the easiest to understand that I could come up with that will match what you want.

```
([A-Z])\d\d\d\d\d-00\d
```

Here is a tutorial on it like requested:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex

Comment: He's using < C++11, he says.